# marshallow-dataclass throws validation exception

Tags: python, marshmallow, python-dataclasses, python-3.7

I have the following simple example:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
import marshmallow_dataclass

@dataclass
class Tst:
    fld: str


if __name__ == "__main__":
    objct = marshmallow_dataclass.class_schema(Tst)().load("{\"fld\":\"value\"}")
```

I expected this to deserialize an object from the JSON, but the following traceback was the result:

```
Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./main.py", line 13, in <module>
    objct = marshmallow_dataclass.class_schema(Tst)().load("\"fld\":\"value\"")
  File "/home/krjoff/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/marshmallow/schema.py", line 720, in load
    data, many=many, partial=partial, unknown=unknown, postprocess=True
  File "/home/krjoff/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/marshmallow/schema.py", line 898, in _do_load
    raise exc
marshmallow.exceptions.ValidationError: {'_schema': ['Invalid input type.']}
```

Can someone suggest how to fix this?

Comment: Use `loads`, not `load`.  `loads` is for json, `load` is for a python list or dict.

Comment: @snakecharmerb Thanks much. That what the problem was about.

Comment: But `"\"fld\":\"value\""` is not a valid json string representation. It has to be `{"\"fld\":\"value\""}`